# How use more than one domain shared port with MuleSoft Api proxys?

Tags: mule, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

We had a dedicated Mule runtime server that hosts several Mule API Proxies.
We need to share a second SSL port for a new Proxy API.

Is it possible to have more than 1 HTTPS ports defined in `proxy-shared-domain`? And if so, how to select the right port at the API proxy configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have several HTTP Listener configurations in your domain, the same as in a Mule application. Each HTTP Listener has to listen to a different port. In a proxy, which is just a simplified Mule application, just reference the right HTTP Listener configuration by name from the HTTP Listener source in the flows. You probably need to download and edit the proxy by hand so it points to the configuration that you want.

Comment: Thank you. If I simply change the http-proxy.xml file directly in the server, an update will override the file?

Comment: It has been a while since I used it but I think that is possible.

Comment: In my environment I downloaded the proxy jar, edited, and then deployed through runtime manager.